# What is the correct method for deallocation of object in the following method?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Can any please tell which one is the best method in the following method?

```
@implementation Person
@synthesize name;
- (void)dealloc { [self.name release]; [super dealloc]; }
@end



 @implementation Person
    @synthesize name;
    - (void)dealloc { [name release]; [super dealloc]; }
    @end



@implementation Person
@synthesize name;
- (void)dealloc { [name release]; name = nil;[super dealloc]; }
@end
```

Comment: i believe all are the same since you are not changing the instance variable when you synthesize, hence you access the getter and setter the same way as the instance variable.

Comment: Are you using the ARC enable or not?i Suggest to use ARC

Comment: First one should be avoided, it is suggested not use `self.iVar` in dealloc.

Third option if feel is the best, as it takes care of any dangling pointer when it has been set to `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

Well 1st one is definitely wrong:

[(From Apple's documentation)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html)

> **Don’t Use Accessor Methods in Initializer Methods and dealloc**. The only
>   places you shouldn’t use accessor methods to set an instance variable
>   are in initializer methods and dealloc.

---

Now the 2nd one is what Apple uses in their example apps.

---

In my opinion though the last one is (may-be) best because by setting the pointer to `nil` ensures that any call to the (released) pointer will just forward the message to `nil` (which is safe, where a call to a released object is not). Also keep in mind that if the property is defined as `retain` setting to `nil` will also call `release`.

Answer (score 0):

This one is the best for me

```
@implementation Person
@synthesize name;

-(void)dealloc { 
   self.name = nil; 
   [super dealloc]; 
}
@end
```

And your first one is wrong wrong wrong

Comment: you shouldnt use synthesized setters in dealloc or init, it can cause unexpected behaviour (e.g. through KVO notifications). the 3rd example is the one i use

Answer (score 0):

For non-ARC version the third one is the best as it take care of released variable by pointing it to the `nil`.

But As recommended by Apple, Please use the ARC for building projects.

From APPLE's Documents

> In Automatic Reference Counting, or ARC, the system uses the same
>   reference counting  system as MRR, but it inserts the appropriate
>   memory management method calls for you at  compile-time. **You are
>   strongly encouraged to use ARC for new projects**. If you use ARC, there
>   is typically no need to understand the underlying implementation
>   described in this document,  although it may in some situations be
>   helpful.